# ncmpcpp stops highlighting current song

Tags: bash, mpd

Hi I'm recently working around with ncmpcpp and I've configured it pretty nicely to what I want. Unfortunately on playlist view, after 3-4 seconds it will stop highlighting the currently played song, and as a result I lose track of where I am in my playlist (even though the song is played in the header).

Is there a way to have the currently played song constantly highlighted? I've looked through the numerous ncmpcpp config options and I couldn't find something to this.

Here's a gif of what is happening:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTI6l.gif

Here is the config file for ncmpcpp: http://pastebin.com/XTdQa2qb

Here is the config file for mpd:

```
music_directory     "~/Music/albums"
playlist_directory  "~/.mpd/playlists"
db_file             "~/.mpd/mpd.db"
log_file            "~/.mpd/mpd.log"
pid_file            "~/.mpd/mpd.pid"
state_file          "~/.mpd/mpdstate"

auto_update "yes"
auto_update_depth "2"

audio_output {
 type        "osx"
 name        "aMat Mac Device"
 mixer_type  "software"
}

audio_output {
  type    "fifo"
  name    "my_fifo"
  path    "/tmp/mpd.fifo"
  format  "44100:16:2"
}

bind_to_address "localhost"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well lesson learned, always read the man page!

There's a ncmpcpp config option `playlist_disable_highlight_delay = 0` which solves the issue of the highlighting fading away. When you set it to 0 it will stay highlighted forever.

Although what would be ideal would be if I could highlight other parts of my playlist and *still* have some indicator on what is currently playing. But c'est la vie, this is a solution.